# How to use scipy.minimize with multiple parameters in error function?

Tags: python, scipy

I have two sets of frequencies data from experiment and from theoretical formula. I want to use minimize function of scipy.
Here's my code snippet.
where g is coupling which I want to find out.
Ad ind is inductance for plotting on x-axis.

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
def eigenfreq1_func(ind,w_q,w_r,g):
return (w_q+w_r)+np.sqrt((w_q+w_r)**2.0-4*(w_q+w_r-g**2.0))/2 
def eigenfreq2_func(ind,w_q,w_r,g):
return (w_q+w_r)-np.sqrt((w_q+w_r)**2.0-4*(w_q+w_r-g**2))/2.0 
def err_func(y1,y1_fit,y2,y2_fit):
return np.sqrt((y1-y1_fit)**2+(y2-y2_fit)**2)  
g_init=80e6
res1=eigenfreq1_func(ind,qubit_freq,readout_freq,g_init)
print res1
res2=eigenfreq2_func(ind,qubit_freq,readout_freq,g_init)
print res2
fit=minimize(err_func,args=[qubit_freq,res1,readout_freq,res2])
```

But it's showing the following error :

"TypeError: minimize() takes at least 2 arguments (2 given)"

Comment: You forgot the initial parameter estimate array

Answer (score 3):

First, the indentation in your example is messed up. Hope you don't try and run this

Second, here is a baby example to minimize the chi2 with the function `scipy.optimize.minimize` (note you can minimize what you want: likelihood, |chi|**?, toto, etc.):

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt
def functionyouwanttofit(x,y,z,t,u):
    return np.array([x+y+z+t+u , x+y+z+t-u , x+y+z-t-u , x+y-z-t-u ]) # baby test here but put what you want
def calc_chi2(parameters):
    x,y,z,t,u = parameters
    data = np.array([100,250,300,500])
    chi2 = sum( (data-functiontofit(x,y,z,t,u))**2 )
    return chi2

# baby example for init, min & max values
x_init = 0
x_min = -1
x_max = 10
y_init = 1
y_min = -2
y_max = 9
z_init = 2
z_min = 0
z_max = 1000
t_init = 10
t_min = 1
t_max = 100
u_init = 10
u_min = 1
u_max = 100
parameters = [x_init,y_init,z_init,t_init,u_init]
bounds = [[x_min,x_max],[y_min,y_max],[z_min,z_max],[t_min,t_max],[u_min,u_max]]
result = opt.minimize(calc_chi2,parameters,bounds=bounds)
```

In your example you don't give initial values... This with the indentation... Were you waiting for someone doing the job for you ?

Third, note the optimization processes proposed by scipy are not always adapted to your needs. You may prefer minimizers such as lmfit